# Laravel : PushNotification for fcm not working on live

Tags: laravel, push-notification, android-push-notification

I am using [PushNotification](https://github.com/edujugon/PushNotification) (by Edujogon) for push notification services.

So, for that I created a file in `config/pushnotification` and set my key and all for `fcm and apn`.

On this file I set

```php
'fcm' => [
    'priority' => 'normal',
    'dry_run' => false,
    'apiKey' => 'My-Api-key',
],
```

And sending on `fcm` key to `sendFCM` function

```php
  if(count($fcmDeviceIds) > 0) {
    $this->sendFCM($fcmDeviceIds, $payload, $addedPost);
  }
```

And my `sendFCM` function :

```php
private function sendFCM($tokens, $payload, $addedPost) {

    $poroductDetail = Product::find($addedPost->product_id)->first();
    $productTitle   = $poroductDetail->title;
    $payloadData    = ([$addedPost, 'notificationType' => 'postNotification']);

    try {
        $push = new PushNotification('fcm');
        $feedback = $push->setMessage([
            'fcm' => [
                'alert' => [
                    'title' => isset($payload['title']) ? $payload['title'] : 'myTitle',
                    'body' => $payload['body']." for ".$productTitle
                ],
                'sound' => isset($payload['sound']) ? $payload['sound'] : 'default'

            ],
            'extraPayLoad' => $payloadData
        ])->setDevicesToken($tokens)->send()->getFeedback();

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        Log::error($ex->getTraceAsString());
    }
}
```

So when I check in local I got all notifications but on live i did'nt gt any notification.What's the problem in my code ?

Comment: are you geting any error or response from server

Comment: No not getting any error, sometime i gt notificvation sometime not

Comment: you need it only for android? If yes,I suggest to use firebase.

Comment: @Javed Can you show cURL request for `send()` function? Also, you did a `Log::error($ex->getTraceAsString());`. So, did logs have anything useful?

Comment: @vivek_23 when i remove `implements ShouldQueue` on my `class ExecutiveNotificationListener implements ShouldQueue` its working

Comment: ok. What does `ShouldQueue` interface want you to implement anyway?